# Лизензия MIT. При использовании сторонних js-библиотек нужно указывать чужой copyright в подвале сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, авторские-права

Использую библиотеки, распространяемые по лицензии MIT. В коде библиотеки, в файле js, написан их копирайт в комментариях, его оставляю. А в подвале своего сайта можно написать только (c)Моя_компания?или теперь нужно что-то добавлять/заменять на чужой?

Comment: Вы разве на страницах своего сайта код выводите? Как информация выводимая на страницах сайта относится к коду библиотеки? :)